# DataReader Feeding a DatagridView Control - Row by Row

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldatareader, stack-overflow

I have a class that handles datareading as such (Note that ischanged is an Event that i am raising to indicate the availability of a new row)

```
public DataRow FetchNext()
{
    DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
    if (dr.Read() && dr.HasRows)  //this will loop through rows unless cancel is clicked
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listCols.Count; i++)
            {
                drow[(DataColumn)listCols[i]] = dr[i];
            }
            dt.ImportRow(drow);
            totalRowCount++;
            this.isChanged();
            return drow;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return drow;
    }
}
```

Another class which uses this class implements reading the rows and inserting them into the datagridview as follows (bs is my bindingsource which is bound to datatable dt)

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myrow = p.FetchNext();
    this.dt = p.dt.Copy();
    bs.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridViewMyData.DataSource = bs;
    bs.ResetBindings(false);       
}
private void handleChanged()
{
    bs.ResetBindings(false);
    dt.Rows.Add(p.FetchNext());
}
```

When I fire everything up i get:

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
_HResult=-2147023895
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code produces the exception?

Comment: the for loop in fetchnext()

Comment: will this `dt.Rows.Add(p.FetchNext());` raise the `handleChanged` event? If so its an endless loop..

Comment: Would that ever raise a stackoverflowexception?

Comment: I have written many algorithms to stream data from sql directly to a gridview, this being the latest, with this bug, without success so far. I am really frustrated in solving this.

Comment: If the endless loop claims any resources it will raise a stackoverflowexception or an outofmemory exception. If not it'll just hang.. an addRow certainly claims resources.

Comment: Indeed, and this was the case. @TaW

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the answer:

```
    public DataRow FetchNext()
{
    DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
    if (dr.Read() && dr.HasRows)  //this will loop through rows unless cancel is clicked
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listCols.Count; i++)
            {
                drow[(DataColumn)listCols[i]] = dr[i];
            }
            dt.ImportRow(drow);
            totalRowCount++;
            this.isChanged();
            return drow;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        return drow;
    }
}
```

In the calling class I implemented a background worker, which on Dowork : fetches Next. While workcompleted also fetches next, reading the value of isEnded everytime.

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myrow = p.FetchNext();
            this.dt = p.dt.Copy();
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridViewMyData.DataSource = bs;
            bs.ResetBindings(false);
            if (!p.isEnded && !backgroundWorker1.IsBusy )
            {
                bs.SuspendBinding();
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
         }


  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bs.SuspendBinding();
        if (!p.isEnded)
        {
            dt.ImportRow(p.FetchNext());
        }

    }
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    bs.ResumeBinding();
    if (!p.isEnded)
    {

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    else
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
    RefreshData();

}
```

This did fix the problem, and the grid is indeed populate row by row. However, for queries with hundreds of thousands of rows, this will be extremely time consuming.